# How to use numpy where for finding multiple records

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy to read csv file.  I am trying to add condition to match the records from csv file. 
my sample team_file looks like this

```
43596,Team1,50,team1data,id1 
43597,Team2,51,team2data,id2
43598,Team3,50,team2data,id2
```

Below is the code

```
import numpy as np
reader = np.genfromtxt(team_file, delimiter=',', usecols=np.arange(1, 3), dtype=None)
```

I want to fetch the column2 when the column3 is 50.
in this example Team1 and Team3 should be the output.

I want to use np.where without writing a for loop.  Is there a way to achieve this using numpy?  i cannot use pandas.
by doing reader[0][1] gives me the value as 50, but how do i achieve it for all the records in the file?
Appreciate any help

Comment: You really should have displayed `reader` for this example.  Then we'd be able to answer without recreating your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [90]: txt=b"""43596,Team1,50,team1data,id1 
    ...: 43597,Team2,51,team2data,id2
    ...: 43598,Team3,50,team2data,id2
    ...: """
In [92]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',usecols=[1,3],dtype=None)
In [93]: data
Out[93]: 
array([[b'Team1', b'team1data'],
       [b'Team2', b'team2data'],
       [b'Team3', b'team2data']],
      dtype='|S9')
```

Can't test for '50'; no such value any of the 'usecols'.

---

If I load all columns, I can test the 3rd field for '50', select the appropriate records:

```
In [94]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype=None)
In [95]: data
Out[95]: 
array([(43596, b'Team1', 50, b'team1data', b'id1'),
       (43597, b'Team2', 51, b'team2data', b'id2'),
       (43598, b'Team3', 50, b'team2data', b'id2')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', 'S5'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', 'S9'), ('f4', 'S3')])
In [96]: data['f2']
Out[96]: array([50, 51, 50])
In [97]: idx = np.where(data['f2']==50)
In [98]: idx
Out[98]: (array([0, 2], dtype=int32),)
In [99]: data[idx]
Out[99]: 
array([(43596, b'Team1', 50, b'team1data', b'id1'),
       (43598, b'Team3', 50, b'team2data', b'id2')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', 'S5'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', 'S9'), ('f4', 'S3')])
In [100]: data['f1'][idx]
Out[100]: 
array([b'Team1', b'Team3'],
      dtype='|S5')
```

---

Correction.  using `arange(1,3)` instead of `[1,3]` to select columns

```
In [102]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',usecols=np.arange(1,
     ...: 3),dtype=None)
In [103]: data
Out[103]: 
array([(b'Team1', 50), (b'Team2', 51), (b'Team3', 50)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'S5'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [104]: idx = np.where(data['f1']==50)
In [105]: data[idx]
Out[105]: 
array([(b'Team1', 50), (b'Team3', 50)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'S5'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Comment: Thanks Hpaul.  I could have provided the data.  Data is coming as array([('Team1', 50), ('Team2', 51),('Team3',50)]).  I cannot use all the columns in the file, because, there are n't fixed number of columns in each row.  Some rows can have 5 cols and the other can have 10 cols.  But i am interested in 2nd and 3rd columns.  And l want to return Team1 and Team3 where the 2nd column matched to 50.

Comment: Something like below seem to work.  However, f1 and f2 values can have different character lengths.  i noticed S9 meant to take 1st 9 characters. 
 but i want to take the entire second and 3rd columns irrespective of the number of characters.  data = genfromtxt('team_file',delimiter=',',usecols=np.arange(1,3),dtype=[('f1','S9'),('f2','<i4')],skip_header=1).      data[np.where(data['f2']==50)]

Comment: I got it working.  Your answer helped, so i marked as correct answer.  I can define 'f1',S20' .  20 chars is the max.  it worked with this. data = genfromtxt('team_file',delimiter=',',usecols=np.arange(1,3),dtype=[('f1','S20'),('f2','int32')],skip_header=1) then called it like data[np.where(data['f2']==50)]['f1']

Comment: Sorry, I carelessly substituted `[1,3]` for `arange(1,3)`.  If column widths vary, then you do want to read the smallest common number.  As for `S9`, genfromtxt` should choose a correct length if dtype=None.